# Postgres: grouping and ranking

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

For our project, we need to calculate idle time of a vehicle parked at an endpoint.
We are given this (simplified) table of events:

```
CREATE TABLE endpoint_event (
    time                    INT,
    event                   VARCHAR,
    endpoint                VARCHAR,
    vehicle                 VARCHAR,
    is_arrival_activity     BOOL
);

INSERT INTO endpoint_event VALUES
(01,'arrival','A','vehicle 1',TRUE),
(02,'unload start','A','vehicle 1',TRUE),
(03,'unload done','A','vehicle 1',TRUE),
(14,'load start','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(15,'load done','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(16,'depart','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(27,'arrival','A','vehicle 1',TRUE),
(28,'load start','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(29,'load done','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(40,'itinerary received','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(41,'depart','A','vehicle 1',FALSE),
(51,'arrival','A','vehicle 1',TRUE),
(52,'unload start','A','vehicle 1',TRUE),
(52,'unload done','A','vehicle 1',TRUE);
```

```
 time |       event        | endpoint |  vehicle  | is_arrival_activity
------+--------------------+----------+-----------+---------------------
    1 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t
    2 | unload start       | A        | vehicle 1 | t
    3 | unload done        | A        | vehicle 1 | t
   14 | load start         | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   15 | load done          | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   16 | depart             | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   27 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t
   28 | load start         | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   29 | load done          | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   40 | itinerary received | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   41 | depart             | A        | vehicle 1 | f
   51 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t
   52 | unload start       | A        | vehicle 1 | t
   52 | unload done        | A        | vehicle 1 | t
(14 rows)
```

The idea is to get the max time of a vehicle at an endpoint for all of its arrival events and the min time of the vehicle at an endpoint for all its departure events (given in the `event` and `is_arrival_activity` columns).

For example -- the vehicle arrives and therefore we need to get the max time when it arrives at endpoint A -- which would yield timestamp 3. Similarly, we need to do the same thing when it leaves and get the minimum timestamp, which would be 14. Idle time would be 11 time units.

My desired output would be as follows:

```
 time |       event        | endpoint |  vehicle  | is_arrival_activity |   grouping
------+--------------------+----------+-----------+---------------------+------------
    1 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
    2 | unload start       | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
    3 | unload done        | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
   14 | load start         | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   15 | load done          | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   16 | depart             | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   27 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          3
   28 | load start         | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          4
   29 | load done          | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          4
   40 | itinerary received | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          4
   41 | depart             | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          4
   51 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          5
   52 | unload done        | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          5
   52 | unload start       | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          5
```

This way I easily get the max timestamp for all vehicles arriving and departing. From here, I could calculate that the idle time would be (14-3)+(28-27).

I tried to accomplish this with `DENSE_RANK()` (and other windowing functions) like this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY vehicle ORDER BY is_arrival_activity DESC)
FROM endpoint_event
ORDER BY 1;
```

The output from this is as follows:

```
 time |       event        | endpoint |  vehicle  | is_arrival_activity | dense_rank
------+--------------------+----------+-----------+---------------------+------------
    1 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
    2 | unload start       | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
    3 | unload done        | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
   14 | load start         | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   15 | load done          | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   16 | depart             | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   27 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
   28 | load start         | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   29 | load done          | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   40 | itinerary received | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   41 | depart             | A        | vehicle 1 | f                   |          2
   51 | arrival            | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
   52 | unload done        | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
   52 | unload start       | A        | vehicle 1 | t                   |          1
(14 rows)
```

Not quite what I want. Does anyone has any suggestions? Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: This would be easy in a programming language, going through the lines one by one.  Are you doing this from an application?

Comment: No. Doing this in SQL since I want to have this data set generated as a DBT model.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would be easier using an iteration in a simple programming language, but if you want it in postgres without functions or other stuff, here it go.

With this solution you can go directly to your result.

```
with sequenced_table as (
    select *, row_number() over() as id
    from endpoint_event
    order by time
)
select sum(timespan) timespan from (
    select *, time - (
        select time
        from sequenced_table seqtable1
        where seqtable1.id = sequenced_table.id-1
          and seqtable1.is_arrival_activity <> sequenced_table.is_arrival_activity
          and sequenced_table.is_arrival_activity = false
    ) as timespan
    from sequenced_table
) as foo
```

Comment: You're the man, thank you for the answer.
The solution is quite simple, my brain was stuck in using windowing functions.